# Revit 2021.1 - DataGridRow.IsSelected property not always true when row is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api

I have searched far and wide, but could not find solution to my problem.
I am writing simple plugin for Revit 2021.1 using c# and wpf.

Here is a DataGrid and its RowStyle in my .xaml file:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="10,0,10,10"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfElementParameterWrappers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              RowStyle="{StaticResource RowToBeSelectedStyle}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="False"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    </DataGrid>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RowToBeSelectedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsObjectSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

DataGrid is binded to a list of ElementParameterWrapper objects in the ViewModel. ElementParameterWrapper object looks like this:

```
public ElementParameterWrapper(Parameter parameter)
{
    Name = parameter.Definition.Name;
    Id = parameter.Id;
    if (parameter.IsShared)
    {
        GUID = parameter.GUID;
    }
}
public string Name { get; set; }
public ElementId Id { get; set; }
public Guid GUID { get; set; }
private bool isObjectSelected;
public bool IsObjectSelected
{
    get { return isObjectSelected; }
    set { isObjectSelected = value; }
}
```

So property IsObjectSelected is binded to the DataGridRow.IsSelected property. However! ElementParameterWrapper property IsObjectSelected is not always true(even though it is selected). On the picture it can be seen how ElementParameterWrapper objects are selected(there are lists binded to datagrid, and on each ElementParameterWrapper object is selected) - [Revit Plugin Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZN4u.png) .

So I do not quite know why sometimes IsObjectSelected property is true and sometimes is false(even though the row is selected).

I tried binding it to a single object(not a list of objects) and still did not work. Moreover, I was using wrappers a few times and it was always working... Could it be connected to the fact that I am selecting each object from two DataGrids?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your wrapper class for any bidirectional binding to work. See [example on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Furthermore, not sure if binding to the `IsSelected` property of the `DataGridRow` is the way to go, rather try to create a `SelectedItem` property in your `ViewModel` (the class hosting `ListOfElementParameterWrappers`) and bind it to the `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem` property in your xaml. The `ListOfElementParameterWrappers` should be of type `ObservableCollection<ElementParameterWrapper>` instead of a generic list ([see this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)).

The resulting code might look like this:

The **wrapper** class:

```cs
public class ElementParameterWrapper:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ElementParameterWrapper(Parameter parameter)
    {
        Name = parameter.Definition.Name;
        Id = parameter.Id;
        if (parameter.IsShared)
        {
            GUID = parameter.GUID;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ElementId Id { get; set; }
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    private bool isObjectSelected;
    public bool IsObjectSelected
    {
        get { return isObjectSelected; }
        set { 
            isObjectSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The **ViewModel** Class:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel (ICollection wrapperCollection){
        ListOfElementParameterWrappers = new ObservableCollection<ElementParameterWrapper>(wrapperCollection);
        SelectedItem = ListOfElementParameterWrappers.FirstOrDefault();
    }
      
    public ObservableCollection<ElementParameterWrapper> ListOfElementParameterWrappers {get; set;}
      
    private ElementParameterWrapper _selecteItem;
    //this property keeps track of the currently selected item in the DataGrid
    public ElementParameterWrapper SelectedItem {
        get {return _selectedItem;}
        set {
            _selectedItem = value;
            //If you need to also change the value of the IsSelected
            //property of the selected item you can do something like this
            foreach (var item in ListOfElementParameterWrappers){
                item.IsObjectSelected= false;
            }
            _selectedItem.IsObjectSelected= true;
            //finally fire the PropertyChanged event
            OnPrepertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The **xaml**:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="10,0,10,10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfElementParameterWrappers, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 
          SelecteItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

          RowStyle="{StaticResource RowToBeSelectedStyle}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
</DataGrid>
```